# How to fetch data from json in android and display in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, json

I am making an android app to fetch JSON data from URL and then showing it in a RecyclerView.

My JSON data

`[{"email":"abc@gmail.com","photo":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/x.jpg","bookname":"one","price":"30","num":"3","avg":"3.9","author":"none"}]`

but only `bookname` and `photo` keys values are fetching. Other parameters are empty but my code is correct because if it is wrong than even `bookname` shouldn't fetch.

My code is:

```html
public class dashBoard extends AppCompatActivity {


    private List<myDash> dash;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    Button read;
    //Creating Views
    int temp=0;
    float starts=0;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    public  String ratenumS,numberS;
   public  String bookName,price,rating;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String mail_one;

    private int requestCount = 1;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_bord);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        //Initializing our superheroes list
        dash = new ArrayList<>();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        getDash();

        //Adding an scroll change listener to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                getDash();
            }
        });

        //initializing our adapter
        adapter = new dashCard(dash, this);

        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


    private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromDash(int requestCount) {
        //Initializing ProgressBar
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);

        //Displaying Progressbar
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        SharedPreferences pre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(dashBoard.this);

        mail_one = pre.getString("mail2", "DEFAULT VALUE");

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest("http://www.example.com/getDash.php?page="+ String.valueOf(requestCount )+"&email="+mail_one,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Calling method parseData to parse the json response
                        parseData(response);
                        //Hiding the progressbar
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);



                        if(temp==0) {
                            Toast.makeText(dashBoard.this, "No More Items Available   "+bookName+"book "+price+" "+ratenumS+"      "+numberS+"  "+mail_one, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            temp++;
                        }
                    }

                }

        //Returning the request
        return jsonArrayRequest;
    }

    private void getDash() {
        //Adding the method to the queue by calling the method getDataFromServer
        requestQueue.add(getDataFromDash(requestCount));
        //Incrementing the request counter
        requestCount++;
    }

    //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            myDash dash1 = new myDash();



            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                //Getting json
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                dash1.setImageUrl(json.getString("photo"));
                dash1.setBook_name(json.getString("bookname"));
                dash1.setNo_down(json.getString("download"));
                dash1.setBook_price(json.getString("price"));
                dash1.setStar_num(json.getString("num"));
                dash1.setAvg_rate(Float.parseFloat(json.getString("avg")));


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Adding the superhero object to the list
            dash.add(dash1);
        }

        //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Does anybody have any idea why this code is not working?

My dashCard Activity.

```html
public class dashCard extends RecyclerView.Adapter<dashCard.ViewHolder> {


    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    //List to store all superheroes
    List<myDash> secDash1;

    //Constructor of this class
    public dashCard(List<myDash> secDash1, Context context){
        super();
        //Getting all superheroes
        this.secDash1 = secDash1;
        this.context = context;
    }

    //In
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.dash_bord, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final myDash secDash = secDash1.get(position);



        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

        imageLoader.get(secDash.getImageUrl(),ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.image, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));


        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(secDash.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.bookName.setText(secDash.getBook_name());
        holder.price.setText(secDash.getBook_price());
        holder.numberD.setText(secDash.getStar_num());
        //holder.rate.setText(Float.toString(secDash.getAvg_rate()));
        holder.download.setText(secDash.getNo_down());
      //  holder.star.setRating(secDash.getAvg_rate());

    }





    public int getItemCount() {
        return secDash1.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        //Views
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView bookName;
        public TextView price;
        public TextView numberD;
        public TextView rate;
        RatingBar star;
        public TextView download;


        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dashImage);
            bookName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookName4);
            price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceDash);
            numberD = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberDash);
            rate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratenumDash);
            star = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rateDash);
            download = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.download);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you not receiving price?

Comment: only bookname and photo are recieving other are empty

Comment: What is data you have received on Android. Are json below is your purpose.

Comment: I do not see the attribute "download" in your JSON data but you try to parse it, probably this is the error, because after this attribute you do not receive anything

Comment: @AfroChase right that is the issue

Comment: thanxx @afrochase that is the only issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem at:

```
dash1.setNo_down(json.getString("download"));
```

Your json has not download key for get value. When code run over this line, an exception has occurred and program go to catch block, other properties will never be assigned data.
I recommend that check json key are exist before get its value.

Comment: ohh yes how stupid i m.Thanxx bro it work now just i didn't see that.You make my day.Again thank u..................................

Answer (score 0):

You dont have "`download`" as key in json because of that an exception is thrown which causes other keys to not assigned